# Larvel 5.8: middleware ignored when calling route from javascript but not from browser

Tags: javascript, laravel, cors

I've a 'cors' middleware that simply does this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found.'], 404);
    if (config('app.env') !== 'production') {
        return $next($request)
                ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    } else  {
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

I added the middleware into `routes/api.php` in this way:

```
<?php

// Rotte /api/v1
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => ['cors'] ], function () {

    ... wrapping all /api/v1 routes

}
```

When I visit an url from my browser, I see in developer options that

[image]

But, when javscript call the same url, the 'option' preflight request fails

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://project.local/api/v1/customer' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What am I doing wrong?

> Note that asking laravel to list my routes, actually shows that cors is applied !

```
php artisan route:list --path api/v1/
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                           | Name             | Action                                                   | Middleware          |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/customer               | customer.index   | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@index            | api,cors,jwt.verify |
|        | POST      | api/v1/customer               | customer.store   | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@store            | api,cors,jwt.verify |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/customer/{customer}    | customer.show    | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@show             | api,cors,jwt.verify |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/v1/customer/{customer}    | customer.update  | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@update           | api,cors,jwt.verify |
|        | DELETE    | api/v1/customer/{customer}    | customer.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@destroy          | api,cors,jwt.verify |
```

Comment: Show us how you've added the middleware to the route group.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added requested info

Comment: Please show us where you've registered `cors` as a Middleware.

Comment: There is a nice package for dealing with this issue: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your middleware with additional headers,

```
 if (config('app.env') !== 'production') {
        return $next($request)
                ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN, X-Requested-With');
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: All your code seems to be alright, except for these missing headers, so they might be the ones causing issues, you can try if it works.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean "Why is the third header mandatory in this case?"

Comment: You are using jwt authentication right, and passing data as well, since you would be passing token with your request Authorization header would be required, and for data X-Requested-With would be required, Content-type to let server know what type of content are you passing, in this case, `application/json`.